# Can You Bootstrap CasperJS Tests?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I bootstrap PhantomJS in my Selenium tests by using [Phanbedder](https://github.com/anthavio/phanbedder).
This downloads and extracts the correct version of PhantomJS to a temp dir and my Selenium tests then use this version.

Is there a similar bootstrapping option for CasperJS?

I am working in a Java project and I already call casper from Java using a process builder.

Answer (score 0):

If you install CasperJS using NPM, it includes some PhantomJS version in its node_modules directory. This is likely an older version.

Otherwise, no (I'm not familiar with such a project).

How would that even work? CasperJS is directly built on top of PhantomJS. It runs *in* PhantomJS. So, you would have to have an additional script for downloading such a version.

You would have to implement it yourself. You can set the `PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE` environment variable to point to your intended PhantomJS executable.

Comment: Like I said, Phanbedder extracts the version of PhantomJS you want to a temp directory. I am running it from Java so I could set the env variable there - thanks. The last step is the Python dependency though.